# Is it possible to have rounded (fillet) edges on a PCB?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

I would like to know if its possible to have the PCB edges rounded.

No, **I'm not talking about having round corners**, or shapes in the PCB.

What I want to know if there are milling bits that allow to have the actual edge rounded.

[image: Side view]

I've seen this before. The PCB edge is so nice to the touch, and feels like a premium board. I would like to do something like this, but I cant find anywhere on internet, and the few PCB factories I've talked to don't know what I'm talking about :(

Comment: If it has been done in mass production it is possible in mass production.  Regardless of that it is possible.  You could do it yourself.  Making your own milling bit is an option for custom profiles or having one made.  All of that said the best way to find out if you can have it done for your purposes is to contact the board houses you're considering ordering from.  Small order quantities are often limited to specific more common processes, but if you're ordering in the thousands the full gamut of their manufacturing capabilities are available.

Comment: The question is not "Can it be done?" but "What will it cost?".

Comment: [Bull nose router bits for rounded edges](https://www.google.com/search?q=bull+nose+router+bit+for+rounded+edges&tbm=isch)

Comment: If anyone is having trouble with the illustration, notice the words "Side view".  That should make what the OP is trying to ask more obvious.

Comment: They can be circular if you want.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, it's certainly possible with the machinery they typically have.

They would have to use a [solid carbide rounding end mill](https://www.harveytool.com/products/corner-rounding-end-mills---2--4-flute---unflared), probably with 1/8" shank only, **and flip the board** for a second operation. And the boards cannot be stacked for those operations. There might be complications with holding the board in the panel until the last second (maybe another operation).

[image]

Sounds expensive and they may not want to do it for a small order. Additional programming and they would have to source the tooling and maintain it.

As one data point, we had one offshore supplier decline to supply countersunk holes (for flat-head screws) on an order of a couple thousand USD. And that was a simpler operation (all from one side). And it could have been done easily as a manual secondary operation (drill press with a stop set).

Answer (score 10):

It might not be perfectly rounded but a "beveled edge" should be common for most manufacturers and should not drive the cost up much.

A board separated by V-cut will also be quite rounded, but they don't look very nice, so certainty not the "premium" feel there.

And as others have said, if you are willing to put money on the table the manufacturer can do just about anything, but they will not even discuss it with you unless you have a profitable relationship with them.

Comment: Having at least a portion of the PCB with a beveled edge is *very* common, particularly for card-edge connectors (e.g. PCI, PCIe, among *many*).

Answer (score 2):

If you can get the manufacturer to do it then yes it can be done. It is possible. I would like to add that if you do this, make sure you keep all planes and parts away from the edge/area of the board that is rounded. A rounded bit will need additional clearance for planes and parts than a normal board so factor that into the design.

Usually manufacturers require clearance ~20mil from edges so if you were to round the edges with a 30mil bit, the total clearance might be something like 50mil from the edge to facilitate all mechanical tolerances.